# Migration of JCoFunction in sapjco 3.x

Tags: jco

I'm migrating from JCO2.x to 3.x. I have rewritten almost the whole code, but with this I cannot move.

Original 2.x code:

```
        JCO.ParameterList input = new JCO.ParameterList();
        input.addInfo("APP_AREA", JCO.TYPE_STRING, 0, 0, 0, JCO.IMPORT_PARAMETER, null);
        input.addInfo("XML", JCO.TYPE_STRING, 0, 0, 0, JCO.IMPORT_PARAMETER, null);
        JCO.Function function = new JCO.Function(
            BAPI_NAMESPACE + "ZZZ",
            input, // input
            new JCO.ParameterList(), // output
            new JCO.ParameterList() // tables
        );
```

My proposed code:

```
        JCoParameterList input = new JCoParameterList();
        input.addInfo("APP_AREA", JCO.TYPE_STRING, 0, 0, 0, JCO.IMPORT_PARAMETER, null);
        input.addInfo("XML", JCO.TYPE_STRING, 0, 0, 0, JCO.IMPORT_PARAMETER, null);
        JCoFunction function = new JCoFunction(
            BAPI_NAMESPACE + "ZZZ",
            input, // input
            new JCoParameterList(), // output
            new JCoParameterList() // tables
        );
```

Thing is that JCoFunction cannot be instantiated in this form in 3.x. Should I create function template? Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.... a little late response...

You have to get the `JcoFunction` from your `JcoDestination`.
e.g.

```
JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager
            .getDestination(destinationName);
JCoRepository repository = destination.getRepository();
JCoFunctionTemplate template = repository.getFunctionTemplate(functionName);
JCoFunction function = template.getFunction();

JCoParameterList input = function_.getImportParameterList();
//set data on input

//execute the function
function.execute(destination);


//access the output
JCoParameterList output = function_.getExportParameterList();
JCoParameterList table = function_.getTableParameterList();
```